# El metodo (Copy()) de las listas en python tiene sentido? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

El metodo `copy()` hace una copia superficial de la lista, pero no le veo ningun sentido para usarla, si quiero hacer una copia de la lista simplemente hago:

```
lista2 = lista1
```

---

En vez de:

```
lista2 = lista1.copy()
```

---

Para que sirve el metodo `copy()`?

Comment: tambien se puede usar b=a[:].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cuando, asignas una lista a otra, lo que haces es pasar una referencia a la primera lista. en cambio, con un copy creas una nueva instancia independiente.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
b[0] = 7
print(a[0])  # devuelve 7


a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a.copy()
b[0] = 7
print(a[0])  # devuelve 1
```